# Get range based on indexOf

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Im trying to access a specific cell, in a row that corresponds to an index. So for index 5, go to cel F6 and do stuff. I’am getting the following error:

> TypeError: isInColumnid is not a function, it is number. (line 23, file "testing4")

This is my code:

```
var isInColumnid = columntosearchid.indexOf(id) 

var valuestoreplace = isInColumnid.getRange('!I:O')
```

Comment: `java != javascript` --- Remove `java` tag.

Comment: `.getRange()` is a method on the Sheet object. As the error states you are applying it to `isInColumnId` which is a number between -1 and n based on it being assigned by the `indexOf()` method. Suggest you post a larger section of your code.

Comment: You're right. I should apply `.getRange` to the sheet itself and then specify what row and column to get, using the index stores in `isInColumnid`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can save yourself a good amount of hassle on this by using the 
math.range(start, end [, includeEnd]) syntax.

You will be able to pass your variables appropriately while also saving lines of confusion.

Answer (score 0):

My obvious mistake was trying to get a range from a number, or applying a method to a result I’ve already gotten. So thinking a bit further, it makes more sense to look for the cell in the respective sheet and telling `.getRange` the exact coordinates by using the existing index as below.

```
var valuestoreplace = sheet2.getRange(isInColumnid+1, 9)
```